# Rstudio organizing project source files

Tags: rstudio

To me, I really enjoy the tabbing in Rstudio's editor. My statistical projects usually involve several files which separately read in source data, organize analytic data, generate tables and graphics, and occasionally modify databases. I'm often switching between .R files while I code up a project.

It's really important to me to have the project files organized in a logical way. It enhances readability for myself and others. However, I don't program them linearly. Sometimes I start toward the end with table/graphic specifications, then start upon programming source data. This leaves the project files unorganized.

Is there any way to change the order of the project files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was raised sometime ago ([see here](http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/suggestions/810-rearranging-tab-order-by-dragging-in-text-editor)). I think the developers haven't addressed this feature request yet.

My work around is to close the files and reopen them in the order I would like them to be arranged.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have never played with Qt, but I would have assumed it would have made short work of that problem.

Comment: Maybe, but the list of suggestions seems quite long (http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/suggestions). They might just have taken care of items with higher priority.