# Rstudio organizing project source files

Tags: rstudio

Is there any way to change the order of the project files (open tabs) in RStudio?

The question has been asked in 2013 ([Rstudio organizing project source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622438/rstudio-organizing-project-source-files)), but I wonder if there are any updates.

Answer (score 0):

Since "RStudio Desktop 0.99." you can just click and drag it.